# Data type of a range expression in OpenSCAD

Tags: types, openscad

In OpenSCAD, a for loop can specify a range in the form `[first:step:last]`, where `step:` is optional.  It seems you can also assign a range expression to a variable.

```
range = [1:10];

for (i = range) echo(i); // works as expected

// But the range expression is _not_ a special form of list
// comprehension because `range` is not a list:

echo(range);  // prints [ 1 : 1 : 10 ]
echo(range[0], range[1], range[2], range[3]); // prints 1, 1, 10, undef
echo(is_list(range));  // prints false

// Also, this results in an error:
echo(len(range));
```

There are times it would be useful for a function or module to have a range parameter instead of requiring two or three individual numeric arguments to achieve the same effect.

Does a range expression have a specific data type or is this an artifact of the implementation?  If there is a specific data type, is there a way (other than process of elimination) for function to test whether a parameter has been bound to a range expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A range expression doesn't have a specific data type.

A range value is indexable. Its elements are numbers but it's not a list.

```
function is_range(x) = is_num(x[0]) && !is_list(x);
```

Comment: Yep, that seems about the best one could do.  Thanks for the sanity check.

Comment: Note that relying on this behavior is not necessarily backward compatible.